# django call a function with in the context_processors.py

Tags: python, django, function, function-call

In my context_processors.py page I am trying to pass a value from one function to another, but it is not working and I cannot understand why it does not work.

Here is my context_processors.py page code:

```
def get_current_page_value(request):
    if request.get_full_path() == settings.MENU_DETAIL_LINK_AA_DETAILS:
        return {'current_page_value02':settings.MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_AA_DETAILS}
    elif request.get_full_path() == settings.MENU_DETAIL_LINK_BB_DETAILS:
        return {'current_page_value02':settings.MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_BB_DETAILS}
    else:
        return {'current_page_value02':settings.MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_CC_DETAILS}


def resume_menu_list(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return {}
    try:
        current_page_val = current_page_value02
```

How can I pass the value **current_page_value02** from **get_current_page_value(request)** to **resume_menu_list(request)**?

I have declared the values in my settings page:

```
'X.core.context_processors.get_current_page_value',
'X.core.context_processors.resume_menu_list',
```

Comment: I think, that you need a middleware in order to do that. Context processors are used to provide additional data to templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the value returned by a function, you have to call it.

```
get_current_page_value()
```

This will return a dictionary, and you can then access individual keys

```
get_current_page_value()['current_page_value02']
```

So you could include `get_current_page_value()['current_page_value02']` in your context processor.

Context processors really should be distinct, and not rely on each other. If you do call the `get_current_page_value` function inside the context processor, then it will be called twice -- once as a context processor, and once inside `resume_menu_list`. That doesn't seem right to me, but I'm not sure what to suggest, as I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.